# The web3 JSON-RPC error message is not clearly, how to decode it?

Tags: ethereum, web3js, metamask

When I ran a web3 function at Remix, it show me the full error message, then I can easily to debug and fix. But when I called function from my own frontend and Metamask, the error message is not clearly. You can check it here https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlWMw.jpg ( pic1: remix, pic2: metamask )

By using estimateGas (https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/21654/correct-syntax-for-estimating-gas-cost-of-a-function-in-web3/21765#21765) I can get the error message. But it's not clearly. I tried to decode data field. The result here https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zd7c9.png . I can see the error message here, but not exactly in right format.

Please help me to decode the error message, using this hex string :
0x08c379a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000017707269636520736c697070616765206465746563746564000000000000000000

Answer (score 1):

Found it.
`web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionSignature('Error(string)') = '0x08c379a0'`

Remove 0x08c379a0 in data string, and decode it:

`web3.eth.abi.decodeParameter('string', '00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000017707269636520736c697070616765206465746563746564000000000000000000') = 'price slippage detected'`